# onetoone or foreignkey for relationship object-properties

Tags: django, django-models

Let say, there is object **Foo** and it has properties **Bar**.

The properties **Bar** are unique for an object **Foo** (each object has its very own properties).

what would be the most efficient way to define such relationship? define foreign key in Foo's model referring to Bar's model? or define one-to-one relation from Bar to Foo (or visa verse)?

django manual says:

> A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a
>   ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation
>   will directly return a single object.

this is confusing statement. which relationship to choose for which job? what about efficiency (# of queries)?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one `Bar` object per `Foo` then use OneToOne relation.  If it can be more than one `Bar` for single `Foo` then use ForeignKey.

As for "reverse" statement:

```
# access to Bar property of Foo in OneToOne relation
foo.bar

# access to first Bar property of Foo in ForeignKeyRelation
foo.bar_set.all().first()
```

In both cases it will be one SQL query, but OneToOne version looks better :-)